# ClientProtocolException when trying to submit request to a SOAP WsdlRequest by setting username and password via Java

Tags: java, soapui

My purpose is to create a Soap UI project with a given wsdl URL, save it and send requests all via Java methods. I a getting `org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException..... Caused by: org.apache.http.ProtocolException: Content-Length header already present` error when I am trying to submit request by setting username and password for an operation.  Find my Java method to send requests.

```
public void runSoap() throws Exception
{
        String projectFile = "SoapUIProjects/TestProjectA-soapui-project.xml";
    SoapUI.setSoapUICore(new StandaloneSoapUICore(true));
    WsdlProject project = new WsdlProject(projectFile);

    int c = project.getInterfaceCount();
    System.out.println("The interface count   ="+c);

    for(int i=0;i<c;i++)
    {
        WsdlInterface wsdl = (WsdlInterface) project.getInterfaceAt(i);
        String soapVersion = wsdl.getSoapVersion().toString();
        int opc = wsdl.getOperationCount();
        String result="";

        for(int j=0;j<opc;j++)
        {
            WsdlOperation op = wsdl.getOperationAt(j);
                String opName = op.getName();
                System.out.println("OPERATION:"+opName);

                WsdlRequest req = op.getRequestByName("Req_"+soapVersion+"_"+opName);

                //Assigning correct u/p to an operation: Generate
                if(opName.equals("Generate"))
                {
                    System.out.println("The operation is Generate.");
                    req.setUsername("u1");//Setting username
                    req.setPassword("u1");//Setting password
               }

               WsdlSubmitContext wsdlSubmitContext = new WsdlSubmitContext(req);
               WsdlSubmit<?> submit = (WsdlSubmit<?>) req.submit(wsdlSubmitContext, false);
               Response response = submit.getResponse();
               result = response.getContentAsString();
               System.out.println("The result ="+result);
        }
    }
}
```

[image: SoapUI Window]

Also refer to the image attached. Can somebody suggest me where am I going wrong and how to resolve this problem?

Comment: Glad to know that you could solved this. Could you please post your complete code here so that it can benefit others? Also, Have you parameterized your request and response. It will be very helpful if you can provide details as to how you have done it. Also, could you please let us know where/how to provide the end point.

Thanks, Mike.

Comment: Hi Mike, for the complete code, please refer to [this](http://pritikaur23.wordpress.com/2013/06/16/saving-a-soapui-project-and-sending-requests-using-soapui-api/) link. You can provide the end point for the requests using the following `req.setEndpoint(“your_end_Point”);` Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I got the answer to my question.
I had to set the 'Authorisation Type' explicitly and programmatically and the code to do so is this -
`req.setAuthType("Preemptive");`

By giving this, the request is being sent and I am not getting any exceptions.

Comment: Thank you very much!  This was my issue as well.

Answer (score 4):

In my search to fix this same error, I found that the solution was to enable "Authenticate Preemptively" option (go into preferences-> http settings and check the 'Authenticate Preemptively' box.)

Answer (score 0):

1) In my case **http** configured in properties instead **https**. I replaced 
   **http** with **https** then its working.

```
https://localhost:8102/WebService/test
```

2) Check Authorization username and Password

3) Select Pre-emptive auth: Authenticate pre-emptively

[image]